# Minimal generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around this idea of minimal generating set. The book gives a definition for it and i've tried looking it up but the definitions are obviously similar. Can someone break it down to simpler terms and provide a basic example?

Here is my books def.

**Generating Set**: If $G$ is a group and $S$ is a subset of $G$ such that $G=\langle S\rangle$, then $S$ is called a generating set of $G$.

**Minimal Generating Set**: A generating set $S$ for $G$ is a minimal generating set if $S\setminus\{x\}$ is no longer a generating set for $G$ for all $x\in S$.

Comment: IN the end, you want to write "... for all $x\in S$."

Comment: Ah, copied that wrong. Good catch!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can think about it as the idea from linear algebra of a *basis* for a space compared to a set of vectors which *span* the space.

A basis is a set of linearly independent elements, where removing one of the elements would result in it being unable to *generate* every element in that space.

In other words, you can think of a *minimal generating set* as a basis for the group, which has no redundant elements while a *generating set* may have redundant elements.

For example, to generate $\mathbb R^3$ we have a basis $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ (a minimal generating set), but this space is still generated by the set of vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}$ (a generating set).

Comment: Thank you! Need to freshen up on my Linear Alg.

Comment: @Ryan Good to hear that you understand it! If you feel that my response was a good answer, I would greatly appreciate it if you marked it as the answer. Linear Algebra is unbelievably far-reaching in mathematics so having a strong foundation is very helpful. If you'd like recommendations, the books "Linear Algebra in Action - Dym" and "Advanced Linear Algebra - Roman" are two extremely well written texts.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look into those textbooks.

Answer (score 11):

For example $\{6,10\}$ is a generating set for the group $2\Bbb Z$ of even integers under addition. In other words, every even integer $n\in 2\Bbb Z$ can be written as a couple of $6$'s and $10$'s (or their additive inverses) added together, i.e., $n=6a+10b$ for some integers $a,b\in\Bbb Z$.  Note that $\{6,10\}$ is also a *minimal* generating system for $2\Bbb Z$ because after removing any of its elements, the rest will not generate the whole group. Indeed, $10\notin \langle 6\rangle =6\Bbb Z$ and $6\notin \langle 10\rangle =10\Bbb Z$. In fact $2$ is in neither.

Comment: Thank you for the easy break down.

Comment: Your example doesn't work; the inverse elements of 4 and 6 are distinct from 4 and 6 themselves, so you should have exactly one of them being negative to ensure a generating set, i.e. $\{-4,6\}$ or $\{4,-6\}$. You can't use multiplication by negative numbers to get around the fact that your group operation is addition.

Comment: @Nij Hagen's answer is fine, under the usual definition of generating sets. (Every element of the group can be written as product of elements of the generating set and their inverses. Equivalently, the smallest subgroup containing the set, which is the definition in the OP, unless you take $\langle S\rangle$ to be the smallest semigroup, which would be strange in this context.)

Answer (score 5):

A *generating set* captures the idea that starting with only a few elements of the group and then applying the group operation can be enough to (eventually) create, or *generate*, every element of the group.

*Minimality* in mathematics is the property of being as small as possible. There is no other thing of the category or description that does what it should and is also smaller than the one you have. Note that this doesn't exclude the possibility for multiple minimal objects of the same size, that is, *minimality* is not necessarily *unique*.

A *minimal generating set* according to the definition provided is thus a set of elements of the group that can be used to eventually form the whole group, but, if even one of those elements is missing, loses that ability.

---

Note that often a *minimal* object is the absolute smallest possible object meeting that description. For example, while $\{4,3\}$ is a generating set for $\Bbb{Z}_6$ under addition and removal of either element leaves a ***non***-generating set, there is already a smaller generating set: $\{1\}$.

Because this can cause confusion due to different ideas about what "is allowed to be" minimal, a set with some defined desired property for which the removal of any element also removes the desired property, may instead be called a *critical set* instead, to avoid ambiguity. Your definition of a *minimal generating set* should rather be applied to a *critical generating set*, with minimality reserved for only the smallest possible case(s). To continue with the same example, the set $\{3,4\}$ is a critical generating set, while $\{1\}$ and $\{5\}$ are true minimal generating sets.

Comment: As I understand it, "minimality" is quite often understood to mean minimality with respect to some partial order on a set. In this case, the partial order of set inclusion. I agree that it can easily be confused with minimality with respect to another (partial or total) order, such as the size of the sets.